# TabLayout setText() and setIcon() not working properly with custom view

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-custom-view, android-tablayout

I am building a Tab Layout with custom text and icon. The tab layout is setup with viewpager. I followed this reference for setting custom view.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(android.view.View)

But the text and icon are not updating when I set with setText() and setIcon().

custom_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java - setUpTabIcons()

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_art_track_black_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_chat_bubble_black_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_person_add_black_24dp
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tab);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabIcons[i]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setText("Random");
    }
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? Any alternative method will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void setupTabs() {
    String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    int[] icons = ----
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        if (mTabLayout != null) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            if (tab != null)
                tab.setCustomView(prepareTabView(titles[i], icons[i]));
        }
    }
}

private View prepareTabView(String title, int icon) {
    View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_tab, null);
    TextView tabTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
    ImageView tabIcon = (ImageView ) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
    tabTitle.setText(title);
    tabIcon.setImageResouce(icon);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your TextView element you should use `android:id="@android:id/text1"` this will be the proper int value (16908308). The same for the icon - id should be `'@android:id/icon'`